# Proof that coprime cubes are divisible by $n$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I would like to ask if my proof is correct. Task is to prove that

$$
n \big| \left( \sum_{0 < a < n \atop (n, a) = 1} a^3 \right),
$$

where $n>2$.

My proof: Take a number $k$ coprime to $n$. Then $n-k$ is also coprime to $n$. If we sum these numbers cubed we get $k^3 + n^3 - 3n^2k + 3nk^2 - k^3 \equiv k^3 - k^3 \equiv 0 \pmod n$. Just to be clear: $n/2$ is not coprime to $n$. So we can pair all of the coprime numbers to get a total sum that will be divisible by $n$.

Comment: Yep, this works.  The only note I have is the statement that $n/2$ is not coprime to $n$.  This is true for $n \neq 2$, in which case the statement is, in fact, false.

Comment: Thanks, Maciek, I updated the question so that only n > 2 would be considered.